# Logstash & Elasticsearch issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I need you pro help to figure what is my issue with the ES & Logstash.

I'm using Elasticsearch 1.1.0 and logstash 1.4.0 to push logs to ES & Kibana .

My servers are located in AWS ( Master -> V.Core (4) , ECU (8) , RAM (15 GB) )
Node is the same .

**My logstash configuration :**
[image]

I'm taking the log files from S3 and put the locally in the Server
after that the logstash take them and push them to ES cluster .
Logstash + Kibana + ES Master (Located in 1 server)
those files are something like 12M size and I have more than 20,000 files.

MY ES configuration (Master)

```
cluster.name: MY-CLUSTER-NAME
node.name: MY-NODE-NAME
node.master: true
node.data: true
path.data: /PATH_TO_DATA/data
path.logs: /PATH_TO_LOGS/logs
```

ES Configuration (Node)

```
cluster.name: MY-CLUSTER-NAME (Same name)
node.name: MY-NODE-NAME (Another name)
node.master: false (This is node not master)
node.data: true
path.data: /PATH_TO_DATA/data
path.logs: /PATH_TO_LOGS/logs
```

For checking the cluster status :

```
http://MASTER_IP:9200/_cluster/health
```

this is the result :

```
{
  "cluster_name": "es-cluster-onetagv2",
  "status": "green",
  "timed_out": false,
  "number_of_nodes": 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes": 2,
  "active_primary_shards": 5,
  "active_shards": 10,
  "relocating_shards": 0,
  "initializing_shards": 0,
  "unassigned_shards": 0
}
```

**my Java version** ( Don't know if this is important ) :

> java version "1.7.0_51" OpenJDK Runtime Environment
>   (amzn-2.4.4.1.36.amzn1-x86_64 u51-b02) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build
>   24.45-b08, mixed mode)

MY issue is that I'm trying to push more than 400 million hits for 1 day ,
and I can push in 24 hours something like 60 million. so I'm always behind.

I can see also that the ES taking 100% CPU USAGE.
but I don't know if this is the problem.

Maybe you can guide me what I'm doing wrong and how I can push big logs to ES fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the input file and give each file different name so that multiple inputs work on it, which helps logstash to read multiple files parallelly by different nodes.

Please increase the number of ES DataNodes to 4, and 2 ES Masters. This can be achieved by running two logstash instances( provides 2 Masters and 2 DataNodes) and 2 Elasticsearch Nodes(provides 2 Data Nodes).

Comment: Thanks for your help but i don't understand what you mean by split the input file ? you mean that i need more then 1 ES node ? cause now i have 1 master and 1 node. maybe it's better to split the logstash from the ES ? i mean 1 server to logstash & files 1 server to master ES and 1 server to data_node ?

Comment: I didn't mean that, to better explain can you please provide your config inside input{} of Logstash.conf file? To correct your statement you have currently 1 Master and 2 Data Nodes running, I recommend to increase it to 4 Data Nodes and 1 Master

Comment: hey NP you can see my logstash config here http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=142adeh&s=8#.U0K2l_mSwg8

Comment: @AmitDaniel Please increase the number of ES DataNodes to 4, and 2 ES Masters. This can be achieved by running two logstash instances( provides 2 Masters and 2 DataNodes) and 2 Elasticsearch Nodes(provides 2 Data Nodes). Please note the increase in performance in 90 minutes by calculating number of records got saved. Please put your metrics here. And your Logstash.conf looks pretty good here.

Comment: Hey Murthy thanks a lot of your response and your help ! i will create 2 masters and 4 nodes. please explain to me what you mean by " please note the increase in performance in 90 minutes by calculating number of records got saved " how do i have to create 2 masters and 4 nodes on all 6 servers i have to save data ? what about the shards , indexes configuration ? leave them as default ? and Thanks again !!!

Comment: @AmitDaniel, can I know your CPU usage for Logstash? Sometime the bottleneck is Logstash!

Comment: @BenLim Thanks for your replay , yes the logstash cpu usage is 80-90 % always, that's why i asked maybe it's better to create 1 instance for logstash 2 Master ES and 2 ES nodes. when i'm using logstash & ES on the same server the cpu is Choked.

Comment: @Amit Daniel Number of records saved by Elastic Search can be obtained by making a Rest GET Api call to http://<logstash_master>:9200/_all/_count. All configuration remains same, u just need to run 2 Logstash + 2 ES servers in four instances of cluster env.

Comment: @Murthy you can explain what is this call ? "http://<logstash_master>:9200/_all/_count"

Comment: This call is used to get number of records saved by logstash into its lucene database using elasticsearch. I recommended to use this call to get count of records saved, so that we can see the performance change happening after increasing number of nodes in cluster.

Comment: @Murthy , Thanks now i understand you. you can explain to me what is the different between those variables ? : index.number_of_shards , index.number_of_replicas . let me know if i need to change something when i add nodes to ES cluster

Comment: no changes are required apart from adding nodes to cluster. I am also not sure about difference between  index.number_of_shards , index.number_of_replicas